# DMA limitation for STM32L0 accessing GPIO

Tags: timer, stm32, gpio, dma

I am using a STM32L072KB microcontroller and tried to get familiar with timers. I wanted to use a timer to toggle a GPIO/LED via DMA.
I read on a book "Mastering STM32" (https://leanpub.com/mastering-stm32) that it is obviously not possible here, to use DMA for directly accessing the GPIO with a STM32L0 core, but I have not found anything in the reference manual which confirms that restriction (https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00108281.pdf):
[image]

Here is the example of the book for a F4-core which uses the timer+DMA and access the GPIO directly:

- https://github.com/cnoviello/mastering-stm32/blob/master/nucleo-f401RE/src/ch11/main-ex2.c

But it seems to be true: I found on a forum a post, that someone supposes that for the L0-core a PWM can be used additionally as a workaround to get work with DMA.

Can someone please explain me, why DMA cannot access GPIO directly on a L0-core and how I can implement a GPIO/LED toggle (perhaps with the PWM proposal)?

Comment: I would suggest to find a TRM for this type of SoCs and read it, though I suspect the best answer is inside some non-public documentation..

Comment: @0andriy that's what the OP did : " but I have not found anything in the reference manual which confirms that restriction"

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean, and see what I wrote afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: GPIO on these MCUs is not connected AHB or APB, but it is connected to dedicated bus directly connected to CPU core. DMA can access only AHB and APB.

It is because DMA can do transfers on System Bus refered as AHB. It can access AHB slaves (RAM and FLASH) and peripherals using AHB-APB bridge which act as AHB slave. Microcontrollers with Cortex-M0+ CPU core can connect GPIO ports to dedicated bus which is not accessible from System Bus (AHB). Instead there is dedicated "GPIO bus" on CPU core. This allows faster and deterministic GPIO access from CPU core without latency caused by AHB transaction from other masters (like DMA). It also allows single-cycle GPIO instructions, but unluckily using this dedicated bus prevent other AHB masters from accessing it at all. It is not limited to STM32L0, or STM32. Other MCU vendors like Microchip design chips in the same way.

You can see it at Figure 1 in STM32L0 Reference manual RM0367, revision 8 at page 56. DMA is connected to Busmatrix (which is implementation of AHB) and can access all peripherals attached to it (SRAM, FLASH refered as MIF Memory Interace). Using AHB-APB bridge it can access all peripherals (like SPI, I2C, RTC, ...), except GPIO. GPIO ports are not connected to this bus, but they are connected directly to Cortex-M0+ core using arrow labeled IOPORT and thus, only Cortex-M0+ core can access it.

[image: STM32 System Block Diagram]

The fact that GPIO port is connected to different bus is indicated by address of GPIO peripheral. Addresses of peripherals like SPI and I2C always begins with 0x**4**xxxxxxx while GPIO port which are connected to different bus begins with 0x**5**xxxxxxx.

> how I can implement a GPIO/LED toggle (perhaps with the PWM proposal)?

Only in software. You need to drive GPIO pin from Cortex-M0+ core, so you can use for example timer with interrupt.

BONUS: GPIO ports are not the only unaccessible region. Cortex-M0+ system region (at addresses begining 0x**E**xxxxxxx) can't be accessed by DMA also. For example, you can't read/write NVIC or SYSTICK registers using DMA.